# Python Print out rounded float plus a string

Tags: python, string, format

How do I print out the rounded total of a bill with the tip included at the end of a string?

```
bill = input('Enter in the bill ($): ')
tip = input('Enter in the tip percentage (%): ')

total_price = float(bill) * int(tip) / 100 + float(bill)

print(f"The total cost for dinner is ${total_price}")
```

I'd like the results to be "The total cost for dinner is $*x.xx*", where *x* depends on what numbers were entered.

I'm not sure where to add the round() function in my print statement.

Comment: Use the `:.2f` format code: `print(f"The total cost for dinner is ${total_price:.2f}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
print(f"... ${total_price:.2f}")
```

or

```
print(f"... ${round(total_price, 2)}")
```

Edit: Thanks for pointing out my mistake ddejohn.

Comment: `:.2f` rounds too. Try `math.pi` with `:.3f`.